# Saving as a new file using input filename and just adding some suffix - Powershell

Tags: powershell

So i know the title is confusing and i apologize for that.

What i need to do is not write in the same file which can be easily done by just putting a path and name and it will create file for me at that path.

But that's not what i want to do i want to take the input file name and add a suffix to it so for example input file name was `ABB` after adding suffix it would become `ABB-Clean` ...

How i can achieve that with Set-Content or is there anyother way which will not require me to change the code.

```
Function Get-FileName($initialDirectory)
{
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | 
Out-Null

$OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
$OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
$OpenFileDialog.filter = "SCD (*.scd)| *.scd|CID (*.cid)| *.cid|ICD (*.icd) | *.icd | All Files| *.*"
$OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
$OpenFileDialog.filename
}
#"C:\Users\UserName\Desktop"
$inputfile = Get-FileName
#$inputdata = get-content $inputfile

#$configFiles = Read-Host 'Enter Complete directory to file'
(Get-Content $inputfile -Raw) |
Foreach-Object { 
$_  -replace '<Terminal .+\/>', '' `
    -replace '(?s)<Terminal .*?>(.|\s)*?</Terminal>', '' `
    -replace '(?s)<Private type="ABB.*?>(.|\s)*?</Private>', '' `
    -replace '(?s)<ConnectivityNode.*?>(.|\s)*?</ConnectivityNode>', ''       
} |

Set-Content Rename-Item "Clean - " + $inputfile 

(GC $inputfile)|?{$_.Trim(" `t")}|SC $inputfile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To split a filename into path and file use `Split-Path` (or use the properties Directory, Name/BaseName, Extension of a file object)

---

```
Function Get-FileName($initialDirectory) {
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null
    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
    $OpenFileDialog.filter = "SCD (*.scd)| *.scd|CID (*.cid)| *.cid|ICD (*.icd) | *.icd | All Files| *.*"
    $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
    return $OpenFileDialog.filename
}

$inputfile  = Get-Item (Get-FileName)
$OutputFile = Join-Path (Split-Path $inputfile) ("{0}-Clean{1}"  -f $inputfile.BaseName,$inputfile.Extension)

(Get-Content $inputfile -Raw) | Foreach-Object { 
    $_  -replace '<Terminal .+\/>', '' `
        -replace '(?s)<Terminal .*?>(.|\s)*?</Terminal>', '' `
        -replace '(?s)<Private type="ABB.*?>(.|\s)*?</Private>', '' `
        -replace '(?s)<ConnectivityNode.*?>(.|\s)*?</ConnectivityNode>', ''
} | Set-Content $OutputFile
```